# what is Callback function for serial port data reading in c++? Here is an example in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, serial-port

Are there any c++ example or references? How we will program in c++ based on what purpose in serial port programming? This is an example in Matlab code. What thing we should consider in c++ programming if we convert this Matlab code to c++.

```
 function DUT_callback(obj, event, DUT_port)
 persistent stored_data;

if isempty(stored_data)
stored_data = [];
end

if ~strcmp(DUT_port.status,'open')
return;
end

if ~DUT_port.BytesAvailable
return;
end

try
new_data = fread(DUT_port,DUT_port.BytesAvailable);
catch exception
fprintf('ERROR: Failed to read from DUT port.  Shutting down.\n');
cleanup();
return;
 end
 data_array = [stored_data;new_data];

 packet.NewPacket = 1;
 while packet.NewPacket == 1
[packet,data_array] = parse_serial_data(data_array);
% Report bad checksum if appropriate
if packet.BadChecksum
end

% If packet was received, do stuff with it
if packet.NewPacket == 1
    % HANDLE RAW GYRO DATA PACKET
    if packet.Address == 86
        % Extract the gyro data
        gyro_x = typecast( flipud(uint8(packet.data(1:2))), 'int16' );
        gyro_y = typecast( flipud(uint8(packet.data(3:4))), 'int16' );
        gyro_z = typecast( flipud(uint8(packet.data(5:6))), 'int16' );

        got_gyro_data = 1;
   %            fprintf('%d\t%d\t%d\n',gyro_x,gyro_y,gyro_z);
    end 

    % HANDLE TEMPERATURE DATA PACKET
    if packet.Address == 118
temperature = typecast( flipud(uint8(packet.data(1:4))), 'single'    );
        got_temperature_data = 1;
  %     fprintf('%3.2f\n',temperature);
    end

    % If we received gyro and temperature data, log it to
    % the workspace if logging is enabled.
    if got_temperature_data && got_gyro_data
        got_temperature_data = 0;
        got_gyro_data = 0;

  if GDATA.logging_data == 1 && GDATA.selected_DUT > 0
    if GDATA.DUT_samples_collected < GDATA.MAX_SAMPLES
    GDATA.DUT_samples_collected = GDATA.DUT_samples_collected + 1;
     end  end end end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really depends on the OS you will be hosting your program on.

Microsoft has decent documentation on their serial interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx

Linux or some other nix your going to be more interested in:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Low_002dLevel-Terminal-Interface

You will find examples in both sets of documentation.